# Timeout while streaming messages from message queue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, ibm-mq

I am processing messages from IBM MQ with a Scala program. It was working fine and stopped working without any code change.
This timeout occurs without a specific pattern and from time to time.

I run the application like this:

`spark-submit --conf spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.allowBatching=true --conf spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.batchingTimeout=15000 --class com.ibm.spark.streaming.mq.SparkMQExample  --master yarn  --deploy-mode client --num-executors 1 $jar_file_loc lots of args here >> script.out.log 2>> script.err.log < /dev/null`

I tried two properties:

```
spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.batchingTimeout 15000
spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.allowBatching true
```

See error:

```
 2021-12-14 14:13:05 WARN  ReceivedBlockTracker:90 - Exception thrown while writing record: BatchAllocationEvent(1639487580000 ms,AllocatedBlocks(Map(0 -> Queue()))) to the WriteAheadLog.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.BatchedWriteAheadLog.write(BatchedWriteAheadLog.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.writeToLog(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.allocateBlocksToBatch(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.allocateBlocksToBatch(ReceiverTracker.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  ReceivedBlockTracker:57 - Possibly processed batch 1639487580000 ms needs to be processed again in WAL recovery
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  JobScheduler:57 - Added jobs for time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  JobGenerator:57 - Checkpointing graph for time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  DStreamGraph:57 - Updating checkpoint data for time 1639487580000 ms
rdd is empty
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  JobScheduler:57 - Starting job streaming job 1639487580000 ms.0 from job set of time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  DStreamGraph:57 - Updated checkpoint data for time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  JobScheduler:57 - Finished job streaming job 1639487580000 ms.0 from job set of time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  JobScheduler:57 - Total delay: 5.011 s for time 1639487580000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  CheckpointWriter:57 - Submitted checkpoint of time 1639487580000 ms to writer queue
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  BlockRDD:57 - Removing RDD 284 from persistence list
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  PluggableInputDStream:57 - Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[284] at receiverStream at JmsStreamUtils.scala:64 of time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  BlockManager:57 - Removing RDD 284
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  JobGenerator:57 - Checkpointing graph for time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  DStreamGraph:57 - Updating checkpoint data for time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  DStreamGraph:57 - Updated checkpoint data for time 1639487580000 ms
2021-12-14 14:13:05 INFO  CheckpointWriter:57 - Submitted checkpoint of time 1639487580000 ms to writer queue
```

Any kind of information would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know much about Scala. Were there any messages in the queue when the time out occurred? It would be useful log MQ exceptions.

Comment: Do you have a broadcast join as part of your job? If so, there is a timeout on broadcast operations that you might be able to increase.